# Tailwind table dropdown overlay

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a problem in dropdown is getting cut off by the scrollbar as like in image .I adjusted overflow-hidden but not work . Currently , I'm using next js , tailwind and @headlessui/react.May I know is there any solution for that ?

[Image One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRFNx.png)
[Image Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moN5F.png)

Dashboard.jsx .This will be main component . From this , DepositWithdrawTable.jsx will call.

```
const DashboardPage = () => {
  const { data: users, isLoading: loading } = FetchUsersService();
  const { data: reports, isLoading: loadingReports } = FetchReportsService();
  const { data: calculations, isLoading: loadingCalculations } =
    FetchFinanceCalculationService();
  const { data: uncheckReports, isLoading: loadingUncheckReports } =
    FetchUncheckReportService();
  const { data: regularCosts, isLoading: loadingGeneralOutcome } =
    FetchRegularCostsDataService();

  let userCount = users?.meta?.totalItems;
  let reportsCount = reports?.meta?.totalItems;
  let income = calculations?.data?.income;
  let outcome = calculations?.data?.outcome;
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        <BreadCrumb title="Dashboard" />

        {loading ? (
          <SkeletonAnimation />
        ) : (
          // Actual content when data is available
          <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-4">
            <ItemCountCard count={userCount} title={"users"} />
            <ItemCountCard count={reportsCount} title={"reports"} />
            <ItemCountCard text={income} title={"income"} />
            <ItemCountCard text={outcome} title={"outcome"} />
          </div>
        )}

        {!loading && (
          <div className="mt-8">
            <OverAllStatusCard calculations={calculations} loading={loading} />
          </div>
        )}

        <div className="mt-8">
          <h1 className="text-gray-600 font-bold text-lg my-5">
            Deposit Withdraw Table
          </h1>
          <DepositWithdrawTable
            uncheckReports={uncheckReports}
            loading={loading}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mt-8">
          <h1 className="text-gray-600 font-bold text-lg my-5">
            General Outcome Table
          </h1>
          <RegularCostTable
            regularCosts={regularCosts}
            loading={loading}
            tableHeight="h-80"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default DashboardPage;
```

DepositWithdrawTable.jsx . This is used to show data list and DepositTableDropDown component is using in this .

```
const DepositWithdrawTable = ({ uncheckReports, loading }) => {
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col w-full ">
            <div className="p-1.5 min-w-full inline-block align-middle">
                <div className="border rounded-lg shadow dark:border-gray-700 dark:shadow-gray-900 h-80 overflow-auto">
                    <table className="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200 dark:divide-gray-700  ">
                        <thead className="bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 sticky top-0 z-[1]">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3 text-start text-xs font-bold text-gray-700 uppercase dark:text-gray-400">Id</th>
                                <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3 text-start text-xs font-bold text-gray-700 uppercase dark:text-gray-400">Requester</th>
                                <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3 text-start text-xs font-bold text-gray-700 uppercase dark:text-gray-400">Amount</th>
                                <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3 text-start text-xs font-bold text-gray-700 uppercase dark:text-gray-400">Type</th>
                                <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3 text-start text-xs font-bold text-gray-700 uppercase dark:text-gray-400">Confirm Status</th>
                                <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3 text-start text-xs font-bold text-gray-700 uppercase dark:text-gray-400">Request Date</th>
                                <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3 text-end text-xs font-bold text-gray-700 uppercase dark:text-gray-400">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody className="divide-y divide-gray-200 dark:divide-gray-700">
                            {loading ? (
                                <>
                                    <SkeletonTableRow cellWidths={['16', '24', '20', '32', '28', '28', '8']} />
                                    <SkeletonTableRow cellWidths={['16', '24', '20', '32', '28', '28', '8']} />
                                    <SkeletonTableRow cellWidths={['16', '24', '20', '32', '28', '28', '8']} />
                                    <SkeletonTableRow cellWidths={['16', '24', '20', '32', '28', '28', '8']} />
                                    <SkeletonTableRow cellWidths={['16', '24', '20', '32', '28', '28', '8']} />
                                    <SkeletonTableRow cellWidths={['16', '24', '20', '32', '28', '28', '8']} />

                                </>
                            ) : (
                                uncheckReports?.data?.map((item, index) => (
                                    <tr key={index}>
                                        <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200 text-start">{item.id}</td>
                                        <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200 text-start"> {item.reporter?.name}
                                        </td>
                                        <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200 break-words text-start">{item.amount}</td>

                                        <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200 break-words text-start">
                                            <span
                                                className={`mr-2 rounded-full px-2.5 py-0.5 text-xs font-medium ${item.type === FinancialType.INCOME ? "bg-green-100 text-green-800"
                                                    : item.type === FinancialType.EXPENSE
                                                        ? "bg-red-100 text-red-800"
                                                        : ""
                                                    }`}
                                            >
                                                {item.type}
                                            </span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200 max-w-[200px] truncate text-start">

                                            <span
                                                className={`mr-2 rounded-full px-2.5 py-0.5 text-xs font-medium ${item.confirmStatus === true
                                                    ? "bg-green-100 text-green-800"
                                                    : item.confirmStatus === false
                                                        ? "bg-red-100 text-red-800"
                                                        : ""
                                                    }`}
                                            >
                                                {item.confirmStatus ? 'Confirmed' : 'Pending'}
                                            </span>
                                        </td>


                                        <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-200 text-start">{item.createdAt}</td>
                                        <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-end text-sm font-medium align-middle" >
                                            <DepositTableDropDown id={item.id}/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                ))
                            )}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

DepositTableDropDown.jsx .This is DepositeTableDropDown component that is used with heartlessUi.

```
export default function DepositTableDropDown({ id }) {
    const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(false);
    const [status, setStatus] = useState();
    const handleReportAction = async (key) => {
        setOpenDialog(true);
        setStatus(key);
    };

    const renderConfirmBox = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                {openDialog && (
                    <ConfirmBox
                        id={id}
                        status={status}
                        setOpenDialog={setOpenDialog}
                        openDialog={openDialog}
                    />
                )}
            </div>
        );
    };


    return (
        <div className="">
            <Menu as="div" className="relative inline-block text-left">
                <div>
                    <Menu.Button className="inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium  border hover:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-white/75">
                        <MoreVertical size={16} className='flex justify-center items-center text-sm font-semibold text-gray-800 cursor-pointer disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none dark:bg-slate-900 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-1 dark:focus:ring-gray-600' />
                    </Menu.Button>
                </div>
                <Transition
                    as={Fragment}
                    enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                    enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                    enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                    leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                    leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                    leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                >
                    <Menu.Items className="absolute right-0 mt-2 w-56 origin-top-right divide-y  divide-gray-100 rounded-md bg-white z-10 shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black/5 focus:outline-none">
                        <div className="px-1 py-1 ">
                            <Menu.Item>
                                <a href="#" className='text-sm block p-2 hover:bg-gray-200 w-full rounded' onClick={() => handleReportAction(ConfirmStatus.ACCEPT)}>
                                    <Check size={16} className="mr-2 inline-block" />Accept
                                </a>
                            </Menu.Item>
                            <Menu.Item>
                                <a href="#" className="text-sm block p-2 hover:bg-gray-200 w-full rounded" onClick={() => handleReportAction(ConfirmStatus.REJECT)}>
                                    <X size={16} className="mr-2 inline-block" /> Reject
                                </a>
                            </Menu.Item>

                        </div>

                    </Menu.Items>
                </Transition>
            </Menu >
            {renderConfirmBox()}
        </div >
    )
}
```